# Open another python file using tkinter button with parameters/entry

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, bots, trading

I'm trying to build a trading bot for binance. I've managed to build the bot and use it via terminal.

However, I want to make a GUI that runs the bot in the same way it would in terminal, except this time with an interface. I've rebuilt the bot to connect to the binance data-stream to test it. By using various "tickers" (eg. ethusdt, btcusdt), I can tune the bot to look at specific streams for price information.

The problem now is that I can start the program using the button (linked to `bot.py`), but I still have to enter the ticker manually in the terminal after it starts.

So my question is- how do I pass the ticker as a parameter to the program so that it starts automatically, and not have to enter it after? I basically want to enter a ticker in the entry field (ticker_entry) and pass it in to the `bot.py` ticker request.

Here's the code I've written for `bot.py`:

```
import websocket
import json
import pprint
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
tmp = [1]


print("eg. ethusdt = ETH/USDT")
ticker = input(Fore.YELLOW + "Enter ticker here: ")
print(Style.RESET_ALL)


SOCKET="wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/"+ ticker +"@kline_1m"




def on_open(ws):
   print('Connection established')

def on_close(ws):
   print("Connection closed")

def on_message(ws, message):

   global tmp
   

   print("waiting for candle to close..")
   
   json_message = json.loads(message)

   

   candle = json_message['k']

   
   is_candle_closed = candle['x']
   close = candle['c']
   
   

   if is_candle_closed:
       
       

       print("\n")
       print(Fore.RED + "Last candle closed at: ")
       print(*tmp, sep= ' , ')
       print(Style.RESET_ALL)
       print("\n")
       print(Fore.GREEN +"New candle closed at: \n{}".format(close))
       print("\n")
       print(Style.RESET_ALL)

       tmp.pop(0)
       tmp.append(float(close))
       
          

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

And here is the code I've written with the `tkinter` module:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = Tk()
WIDTH = 396
HEIGHT = 594
root.title('CheckBot')
root.geometry("396x594")

bg = PhotoImage(file = "rocket.png")

def start_bot(ticker_entry):
    trader = 'bot.py'
    os.system('"%s"' % trader)


#Creating canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

#Setting image in canvas
my_canvas.create_image(0,0, image=bg, anchor="nw")

#Adding a label

my_canvas.create_text(200,30, text="Enter the ticker to trade", font=("Bembo Bold Italic", 15), fill="#cc5200")

ticker_entry = Entry(my_canvas, bg='white')
ticker.pack(pady=50)

my_canvas.create_text(200,100, text="Enter amount to trade", font=("Bembo Bold Italic", 15), fill="#cc5200")

amount = Entry(my_canvas, bg='white')
amount.pack(pady=10)

trade_button = Button(my_canvas, text='Start trading', bg='#00b359', fg='#000099', command=lambda:start_bot(ticker))
trade_button.pack(pady=70)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Make sure to mark answers that assist you as valid by clicking the checkmark next to the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it isn't the best practice to spawn a whole new CMD shell using `os.system()`, and it is better to put all the main functionality in a function, then import that function and call it.

Instead of writing this in the `tkinter` file:

```py
def start_bot(ticker_entry):
    trader = 'bot.py'
    os.system('"%s"' % trader)
```

Take the logic of `bot.py` and put it into a single function like so:

```py
def start_bot(ticker):
    print("eg. ethusdt = ETH/USDT")
    print(Style.RESET_ALL)

    SOCKET="wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/"+ ticker +"@kline_1m"

    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
    ws.run_forever()
```

Then, back in the `tkinter` file, you can simply import the starting function with `from bot import start_bot`, and the logic should stay in tact.

However, if you don't want to change any major aspect of your code, and want to keep using `os.system()`, then there yet another solution to your problem (again, it is highly recommended to use the above solution, since you are not relying on a redundant `os.system()` call which will waste more CPU and RAM resources).

When you run a file, you can specify file arguments in the command line. These arguments get passed to the script, but they don't do anything if they are not used. However, in your case, since you want to access them, you can do it like so:

```py
from sys import argv

# Get the first command line argument
first_argument = argv[1]

# The thing to notice here is that you start from the index 1, since 0 is the script name. (When you run a python script, you are calling the python.exe file, and the script name is the first argument)
```

How does this connect with your question? Well, since you are already running the `bot.py` file in the command line (using `os.system()`), you can add a command line argument to specify the ticker. Then, from `bot.py`, you can get that ticker value from `sys.argv`.

```py
def start_bot(ticker_entry):
    trader = 'bot.py'
    os.system('"{}" "{}"'.format(trader, ticker_entry)) # Pass the ticker after the script name
```

And in the `bot.py` file...

```py
from sys import argv
ticker = argv[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as a command-line parameter.

```
import sys
ticker = ""
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    ticker = sys.argv[1]
```

Then, if `ticker` is not empty, just fill in the text box, and call `start_bot` yourself.

Comment: Tanks, I'll try this.